# How To Create A CKAN Dataset Resources Using Command Line API With Batch File Input

Tags: ckan

I am trying to create CKAN dataset resources using the command line API where the resource_create action and resource metadata are stored in a batch file in jsonl format and the resource files are stored on the ckan server.

I can create the resources individually using the command shown below but this is inefficient as I have a large number of resources to create for each dataset

```
ckanapi --config ckan.ini action resource_create \
package_id=3c14d814-d8ea-4f5c-9650-240bf74cf621 \
name="resource 1 name" \
description="resource 1 description" \
upload@/migration/data1.csv
```

The CKANAPI documentation does not give an example of a batch file where the action is resource_create but does for resource_patch, which is -

```
$ cat upload-files.jsonl
{"action":"resource_patch","data":{"id":"408e1b1d-d0ca-50ca-9ae6-aedcee37aaa9"},"files":{"upload":"data1.csv"}}
{"action":"resource_patch","data":{"id":"c1eab17f-c2d0-536d-a3f6-41a3dfe6a2c3"},"files":{"upload":"data2.csv"}}
{"action":"resource_patch","data":{"id":"8ed068c2-4d4c-5f20-90db-39d2d596ce1a"},"files":{"upload":"data3.csv"}}
$ ckanapi batch -I upload-files.jsonl --local-files
```

Based on the resource_patch example above, and a lot of googling I've made come up with a batch file format as follows

```
$ cat /migration/create_resource.jsonl
{"action":"resource_create","data":{"package_id":"3c14d814-d8ea-4f5c-9650-240bf74cf621","name":"resource 2 name","description":"resource 2 description","url":"/migration/data2.csv","files":{"upload":"/migration/data2.csv"}}}
```

Using this as input to the api batch command will create the resource metadata but does not upload the file.

Does anyone know what the correct format of the batch file should be?